# Get data in file without indicating a particular filepath

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am tasked to create a web service API where for an example, when an URL `http://localhost:12345/api/filereader/data.txt` is entered in the web browser, the data which is in data.txt file has to be displayed in the web page. I am able to do it if I know the filepath of data.txt.

However another requirement is that I am not supposed to indicate the filepath (in my code) as the scenario is, user is supposed to be able to use the URL API and input the .txt file name as a parameter (from whichever computer/server they are using) to get the data of what is in the .txt file that they have indicated. Therefore there should not be any physical path in my code. Is it possible to achieve that?

Here is the code that I have tried (with filepath):

**ReaderController.cs**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(String FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = FileName;

            string path = "C:\\Users\\attsuap1\\Desktop\\" + fileName;

            string result = File.ReadAllText(path);

            var resultDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
            return Ok(resultDTO);
        }

        catch
        {
            var result = "File does not exist";
            return Ok(new { ErrorMessage = result });
        }
    }
```

How do I edit this code to get what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking to load a file from a user device from your server. That is just not possible for security purposes (imagine what would happen if you could).

The only way to get access to a file from the user, is by letting the user send it using some sort of upload form or control. The posted data can be used by your server then.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me. How do i let user send the file (.txt file) using some control?

Comment: I want to get the user to input the .txt file in parameter instead of html page. Is it possible? As eventually i need the data to be shown in JSON.

Comment: No. That is no possible. You need to POST the actual file content.